# Python httplib2 exception not thrown as expected

Tags: python, httplib2

I wrote a script to run python http request functions
The code is as following:

```
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
data = {'username':"admin", 'passwd':"passwd"}
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
http = httplib2.Http() 
http.force_exception_to_status_code = False
try:    
    print "force_exception_to_status_code"+http.force_exception_to_status_code
    response, content = http.request(self.url, 'POST', headers=header, body=data)
    print response

except httplib2.RedirectMissingLocation:

    print "Error"
```

The console gave me:

force_exception_to_status_code=True

{'status': '302', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server'.....)

But the exception was not thrown, even if I have already set the force_exception_to_status_code to false.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at httplib2's [github repository](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/blob/f9f797223d075874b0031aea832152688ec23fef/python2/httplib2/__init__.py) and you will find between lines 1367 and 1400 that if the status is a 300 then it will raise RedirectMissingLocation. However for a 302 it will not raise the exception that you are looking to catch.